# redux shopping cart with decreasing the item quantity

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to implement redux shopping cart program with reduct option.
cart.js page

```
const addedIds = (state = initialState.addedIds, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      if (state.indexOf(action.productId) !== -1) {
        return state
      }
      return [ ...state, action.productId ]

      case REDUCT_FROM_CART:
       return state.filter(productId => action.productId !== productId)
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const quantityById = (state = initialState.quantityById, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const{ productId } = action
      return { ...state,
        [productId]: (state[productId] || 0) + 1
      }

      case REDUCT_FROM_CART:

      return { ...state,
        [productId]: state[productId] - 1
      } 
      default:
      return state
  }
}
```

& this is ProductItem Page

```
const ProductItem = ({ product, onAddToCartClicked, onReductFromCartClicked }) => (
  <div style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
    <Product
      title={product.title}
      price={product.price}
      quantity={product.inventory} />
    <button
      onClick={onAddToCartClicked}
      disabled={product.inventory > 0 ? '' : 'disabled'}>
      {product.inventory > 0 ? 'Add to cart' : 'Sold Out'}
    </button>
    <button 
    onClick={onReductFromCartClicked}
      disabled={product.inventory < 0 ? 'disabled' :'' }>
      {product.inventory < 0 ? 'No Item' : 'Reduct from cart' }
    </button>

  </div>
)
```

What all changes make this program to run properly with reduct feature? Is there any other code part need to change rather than above given code?? Please anyone help me to sort out this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
case REMOVE_TO_CART:
        console.log("removed ADD");

      return [ ...state.slice(0,state.indexOf(action.productId),
          ...state.slice(state.indexOf(action.productId)+1))
      ];
    default:
      return state
```

this code may be helpful to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Leya. But I need the complete changes that I'll have to make in my code..Is there anyone for help me please??